# jQuery errors in IE7

Tags: jquery

On this site http://church.allthingswebdesign.com/Contact-Us.php, the links on the left work fine in every browser except IE. In IE7 i see there are javascript errors but i can't figure out what the error would be.

Here is the snippet of jQuery that is being executed on this page.

Can anyone tell me why I am seeing javascript errors in IE7?

```
//slides the left sidebar links when the button is clicked
    $('div.links').hide();
    $('div.boxes h3 a.button').click(function(e) {

    var $links = $(this).parents('div.boxes');

    $(this).parents().children('div.links').slideDown(500);
    $links.slideDown(500).animate({

        //if the left property = 0, move it to the left as many pixels as it is wide,
        //else move it back to 0
        left: parseInt($links.position().left,10) == 0 ? (-$links.outerWidth()-2) : 0
    }, 500);

    e.preventDefault();
})

//scrolls the upcoming events
function scroll() {
    $('#events ol li:first').slideUp(function(){
        $last = $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).show().css('borderBottom', 'solid 1px #d1d3dc;');
        $last.prev().css('borderBottom', 'solid 1px #d1d3dc');
        $('#events ol li:last').css('borderBottom', 'none');

    });
}
```

Comment: When IE7 throws an error, it gives a description when you click on it, what is the actual error? It's there for a reason :)

Comment: Also turn off the two "Disable Script Debugging" options, and also "Show Friendly Error Messages" this will provide better debug information. These are in internet explorer's advanced options.

Comment: @Catfish - The error has something to do with your event scroller.  Go to your site, don't touch anything, you will get a JS error in 3 seconds (about the time your events want to scroll).  I would start there.

Comment: It says invalid argument on line 117, but line 117 is in the html markup, not in my script tag section.

Comment: @catfish - it is line 117 of jquery.min.js.  You will not be able to debug that directly, especially in the min file.

Comment: The site works without errors here in IE7...even leaving it alone as as comments above state, am I missing something...or was it resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if these will fix it, but they're a good start:

1. Put it through JSLint.
2. Remove the semicolon within your css values.
3. Cache $(this) to a local variable for speed improvements `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: It was the semicolon in this line 
$last = $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).show().css('borderBottom', 'solid 1px #d1d3dc;');